# Pagination from AngularJS ui not visible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a simple dataset that I want to paginate using angular-js ui. It's server driven pagination since it can get quite big.

Now, I have the problem that my pagination element is not showing up.

```
<pagination total-items="totalItems" page="filterCriteria.pageNumber"></pagination>
```

is what I have, these two parameters are both correct (tested that).

At first I thought I might not have all the correct files imported, but after some checking I can't seem to find anything missing:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- load jquery -->
<script src="js/angular-file-upload-shim-min.js"> </script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script><!-- load angular -->
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

Any thoughts why the pagination element does not show up on my page?

Comment: have you put 'ui.bootstrap' into dependencies of your module? check the source in the browser whether pagination directive was correctly replaced by its template

Comment: No I did not, just discovered it myself. Thanks

Comment: I hope that you are aware that you don't need jQuery nor Bootstrap's JavaScript to use angular-ui/bootstrap!

Comment: Yeah, I know, I'm aware of this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So as I commented you didn't put ui.bootstrap dependency into your module

```
angular.module(appName, [
   'ui.bootstrap' 
]);
```

Comment: so annoyed with myself and in love with you right now!